# Not fill System Databases from SQL Server to Combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have Project about my work. I fill Database from any server but ı dont want to fill system databases(tempdb,master,model....). I cant do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create the database inside the master database just create it outside.

```
create database database_name;
```

Then create you tables inside that schema.

```
create table database_name.table_name ();
```

Comment: No, I want to load databases to Combobox from sql Server except System Databases. I can try but all Databases is load. I dont want it

Comment: You are not even stating how you want to do it. Java, SQL or any other method ?

Comment: For example , The Server Name is oServer. I want to load to combobox oServer has Databases. Yeah I got it.Some databases are filling but system Databases load to combobox. So I dont want it just only want other databases that is created by me . I use c# and MSSQL. its simple :S